# a href name issue in D8 Editor Advanced link

Tags: drupal-8

I have recently installed D8 Editor Advanced link and set(content and format)

```
<a href hreflang data-entity-type data-entity-uuid id rel target title class="">
```

And when i enter a link through editor

I got options like

```
URL
Title
```

And i enter url then name but i got output like

```
<p><a href="url" title="title">url</a></p> (from ck editor source)
```

[image]

output like

[image]

I expect title instead of url as a tag name.please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's an issue with [Editor Advanced Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link).

The `title` here **is not the visible texte** but the **title HTML attribute** (as explain by the field description).

If I understand properly your question, you want to achieve something like `<a href="url>title</a>`. Using CKeditor, when you want to add a link, you should before write the **visible text** then applying a link wrapping it.

Here is an example GIF on a project also using [Editor Advanced Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link):

[image]